# Issue with document.write

Tags: javascript, html

I tried some thing like this,

```
  <script>
    function sample(image){
            document.write('<img src="photo/'+image+'" width=200 height=200/>');
         //document.open("photo/"+image);
    }
</script>

<select name="selection">
          <option onmouseover="return sample('07A31A1250.jpeg')">Aaaaaaaa</option>
          <option onmouseover="return sample('07A31A1251.jpeg')">Bbbbbbbb</option>
          <option onmouseover="return sample('07A31A1251.jpeg')">Cccccccc</option>
          <option onmouseover="return sample('07A31A1250.jpeg')">Dddddddd</option>
  </select>
```

I code this for the purpose of displaying the specified image in sample method when ever the mouse is over on it..
But when i placed/over mouse pointer onto the option,the corresponding image isn loading in entire page instead of showing it like a pop-up. How to solve my problem.???

and it is supported in firefox browser but not in chrome.Is there any work around to do it in browser that doesn't support mouse over options??

Comment: Stop using `document.write`. That will solve a lot of problems for the rest of your life.

Comment: MarcB is right. [Learning jQuery](http://jqfundamentals.com) or direct [DOM manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference) is the way to go. If you want to see a source code as a answer then please specify wat exactly do you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.write` is deprecated. 

Instead perhaps    use something like

```
function fubar)(){
 document.getElementById('foo').value="";
 document.getElementById('foo')="<img src='photo/+image+.jpeg'>";
}
```

another way is to use CSS and put the image in the options

```
img{display:none;}
option:hover img{display:inline;}
```

but the CSS change isn't permanent unlike Javascript

Answer (score 2):

document.write dates back to day 1 of javascript, and predates all of the fancy DOM stuff we can do these days. You can only call document.write during the time the page is actually loading. If you call document.write afterwards, you're replacing the current document (your entire page) with whatever you're trying to .write().

As well, document.write's output (when used properly) goes into the EXACT spot where document.write was called, so even if your code was working, you'd end up with:

```
<option onmouseover="<img src="photo/07A31A1250.jpeg" width=200 height=200/>">Aaaaaaaa</option>
```

which is not what you want.

Look into using [jquery](http://jquery.org) for this sort of thing, and use proper DOM manipulation techniques.